# How to get https on Mercurial?

Tags: https, mercurial, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a publicly available repo url and would like to make a self signed cert to have encrypted transmissions between my HG and my PC (https)

What do I need to accomplish this?

I have tried to look for guides in Google but couldn't get one.

Thanks for the help

PS: I have Ubuntu server 14.04

Comment: I believe SSL is configured in the web-server you use to publish the repository (e.g. Apache). See http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories#hgweb and http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html .